# AngularJs $http response from a website

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

Hello i need to show the response from a website (200, 404, etc) using REST services.

i have created a partial code but i dont  know how show the result

This is js

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http ({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http:/www.google.com'
    }).
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.greeting = response.data;
        });
})
```

and this is html

```
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
      <p>Result = {{greeting.content}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: check the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The `response` is a `IHttpPromise<T>` which extends `IPromise<IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>>`.

The interface for this looks like this:

```
interface IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T> {
    data?: T;
    status?: number;
    headers?: IHttpHeadersGetter;
    config?: IRequestConfig;
    statusText?: string;
}
```

So you can access what you need with:
`response.status`

With your code:

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('Hello', HelloController)

function HelloController($scope, $http) {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://enable-cors.org'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
         var text = "The status: " + response.status;
      
         $scope.directResponse = response;
         $scope.greeting = {content: text};
         $scope.someVariable = text;
     });
  
}

/*
var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");

$http.get("http://enable-cors.org/").then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="Hello">
    <p>Status = {{directResponse.status}}</p>
    <p>Result = {{greeting.content}}</p>
    <p>Result = {{someVariable}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i have try to change but nothing happen

Comment: Your URL (http:/www.google.com) is wrong (only one slash). And you need to set CORS to see the status code. I used for testing purposes: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: i have try this code but not run : angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://enable-cors.org/").then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.status);
    }).
    then(function(response) {
      $scope.greeting = "My data: " + response.data + " Status: " + response.status;
    });
  });

Comment: This won't work, your URL is still wrong. Copy mine from my example. You did forget the protocol.

Comment: i have copy your js but i don't understand what html value i must write in .html file with this modify

Comment: Copy & Paste the last code section. (below //your code)

Comment: this is my html but not show result   <body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
      <p>{{greeting.response}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>

Comment: You just needed to cut out the `.response` from `greeting` before.. but I provided a full example.. look again above

Comment: ok thank you, very much I need to study more about this $http :(

Answer (score 0):

You should really be putting your $http calls into a separate service and injecting that into the controller.

so something like this:

```
angular.module('demo')
.factory('greetingService', function($http) {
   this.getGreeting = function() {
        return $http ({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http:/www.google.com'
        }).then(function(response) {
           return response.data
        });
   }
};
```

Then inject the service into your controller and call greetingService.getGreeting and then set your $scope variable to the result.

Also make sure you have the proper headers in your request.

Comment: While it's a good practice to do this in a decent size project with combination of data-model handling, I don't see why it's a must to wrap `$http` in a separate service, alone. Nor it is relevant to this question. `$http` itself is a service, too.